# Honda CRV - Service Intervals

Tags: oil-change, service-intervals

I have question about servicing for my 2016 Honda CRV, Honda Service says:

> You have to bring your SUV  either 10000km or 12 months

Since I haven't driven 10000km yet should I take my car to service after 12 months?

Why should I take my car to service where I hardly make in 12 months 6000km? Is there a life expectancy for the oil?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

In order to maintain the manufacturer's warranty on the car you need to service it either every 10,000 km or 12 months whichever milestone is reached first.

Once you are out of warranty you can look at choosing a longer life oil that is more suited to your driving patterns - but for now it's just not worth risking voiding the warranty for the sake of the cost of an oil change.

As regards *why* there is a time interval and not just the distance traveled the reasons for this are twofold:

1. The performance of the oil will [degrade over time](https://www.yourmechanic.com/article/what-is-the-shelf-life-of-motor-oil) as a result of things like temperature variations, exposure to humidity etc although this is likely to be over a longer time span than the 12 months there will be a level of drop off.
2. Doing low miles in 12 months typically indicates that the vehicle does mostly short journeys - this can mean for many of the miles it does the oil is not getting hot enough to evaporate the water vapor that condenses in it (this is a normal by product of the combustion process) and this affects the performance of the oil. It can also be an indicator of traveling in largely congested areas - which in turn means that although the distance traveled is relatively low the time the oil has actually spent in a running engine is much higher.

Answer (score 0):

You need to respect either the distance specification or the time specification whichever comes first, that is why they are given - especially if the vehicle is still in the warranty period.

I did, however, use a high quality synthetic oil for double the distance spec (10,000) but changed the filter at the normal distance (5000). This was on a Volvo with a Nissan diesel engine (conversion before someone says Volvo don’t use Nissan engines) and so far out of warranty....